# Confusion regarding Riemann normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand Riemann normal coordinates. This "simple" example using the surface of a unit sphere is from http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~macpd/gen_rel/snotes.pdf (p26). The “north pole” $\theta=0$ is the initial point. The geodesics radiating from the north pole are lines of constant $\phi$. The new coordinates $\xi$ and $\eta$ are related to the old (ordinary spherical) coordinates by $$\xi=\theta\cos\phi$$ and$$\eta=\theta\sin\phi.$$

I'm assuming (quite possibly incorrectly) that these are arbitrary definitions. They then say the metric is$$ds^{2}=d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2}$$
 $$=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\xi^{2}\theta^{2}+\eta^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\eta^{2}\theta^{2}+\xi^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)$$
 where $\theta=\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}.$

Can anyone please explain where the second metric comes from and also why $\theta=\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}$? Thank you.

**This edit added 18 Sept 2014**

Right, I'm going to wander off on my own with this and see where I get. Substituting $\eta$ and $\xi$ into the metric gives

$$ds^{2}=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\xi^{2}\theta^{2}+\theta^{2}\sin^{2}\phi\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\eta^{2}\theta^{2}+\theta^{2}\cos^{2}\phi\sin^{2}\theta\right).$$

Note that for a unit sphere (with the $x,y$ plane passing through the equator) $$x=\sin\theta\cos\phi,$$ $$y=\sin\theta\sin\phi.$$
  This gives$$ds^{2}=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\xi^{2}\theta^{2}+\theta^{2}y^{2}\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\eta^{2}\theta^{2}+\theta^{2}x^{2}\right)$$

$$ds^{2}=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{2}}\left(\xi^{2}+y^{2}\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{2}}\left(\eta^{2}+x^{2}\right)$$
 $$ds^{2}=d\xi^{2}\frac{\left(\xi^{2}+y^{2}\right)}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)}+d\eta^{2}\frac{\left(\eta^{2}+x^{2}\right)}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)}.$$
 And then I grind to a halt. The metric is supposed to reduce to $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$, but I can't see how it does.

Just a thought, but is it useful to point out that for small angles (where $\theta=\sin\theta)$, $\eta\approx y$ and $\xi\approx x$? The above metric then reduces to $$ds^{2}\approx d\xi^{2}+d\eta^{2}.$$

Is this what should happen for Riemann normal coordinates?

**This edit added 21 September 2014**

Following the latest hint from @Semsen
$$ds^{2}=\frac{\zeta^{2}}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\zeta^{2}+\frac{2\eta\zeta}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\zeta d\eta+\frac{\eta^{2}}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\eta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\cos^{4}\phi\{\frac{1}{\zeta^{2}}d\eta^{2}-2\frac{\eta}{\zeta^{3}}d\eta d\zeta+\frac{\eta^{2}}{\zeta^{4}}d\zeta^{2}\}$$

$$ds^{2}=\frac{\zeta^{2}}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\zeta^{2}+\frac{2\eta\zeta}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\zeta d\eta+\frac{\eta^{2}}{\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}}d\eta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\frac{\zeta^{4}}{\theta^{4}}\{\frac{1}{\zeta^{2}}d\eta^{2}-2\frac{\eta}{\zeta^{3}}d\eta d\zeta+\frac{\eta^{2}}{\zeta^{4}}d\zeta^{2}\}$$

$$ds^{2}=\frac{\zeta^{2}}{\theta^{2}}d\zeta^{2}+\frac{2\eta\zeta}{\theta^{2}}d\zeta d\eta+\frac{\eta^{2}}{\theta^{2}}d\eta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\frac{1}{\theta^{4}}\{\zeta^{2}d\eta^{2}-2\eta\zeta d\eta d\zeta+\eta^{2}d\zeta^{2}\}$$
 $$ds^{2}=\frac{1}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}\zeta^{2}d\zeta^{2}+\theta^{2}2\eta\zeta d\zeta d\eta+\theta^{2}\eta^{2}d\eta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\{\zeta^{2}d\eta^{2}-2\eta\zeta d\eta d\zeta+\eta^{2}d\zeta^{2}\}\right)$$
 $$ds^{2}=\frac{1}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}\zeta^{2}d\zeta^{2}+\theta^{2}2\eta\zeta d\zeta d\eta+\theta^{2}\eta^{2}d\eta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\zeta^{2}d\eta^{2}-\sin^{2}\theta2\eta\zeta d\eta d\zeta+\sin^{2}\theta\eta^{2}d\zeta^{2}\right)$$

$$ds^{2}=\frac{d\zeta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}\zeta^{2}+\eta^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}\eta^{2}+\zeta^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\frac{2\eta\zeta d\zeta d\eta}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}-\sin^{2}\theta\right)$$

If I could only now get rid of the right-hand term I'd have the original metric. But how to get rid of this term?

Comment: $\theta$ is just the radius coordinate function, in an uncommon notation. What do you mean by 'second metric'? These are just polar coordinates in a non Euclidean setting (I did not check the formulae, though).

Comment: I just can't see how they derive the $=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{4}}$ etc metric from the information given.

Comment: $$\sqrt{\xi^2 + \eta^2} =\sqrt{\theta^2\cos^2\phi + \theta^2\sin^2\phi} = \sqrt{\theta^2(\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi)} = \sqrt{\theta^2} = \theta$$

Comment: @wspin Thanks. That bit is now clearer. Is $\theta=\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}$ a necessary condition for Riemann normal coordinates? Any chance of a hint as to how the metric is derived?

Comment: @Semsen Why did you delete your answer and my subsequent comments? With your help I thought I was on the brink of answering my question. I'm puzzled.

Comment: The metric should only reduce to $\delta_{ab}$ at the origin of the coordinate system, i.e. at $\xi = \eta = 0.$ (If $g_{ab}=\delta_{ab}$ everywhere, the space is flat!) The approximation you're looking for is true in the sense that $g_{ab} = \delta_{ab} + O(\theta^2).$

Comment: @Peter4075 I think you already have solved the problem: just note the Taylor series of $sin(\theta)$ around zero. Additionally, I wanted to comment on your computations: I think it would be much nicer if you use "matrix of the corresponding metric tensor with respect to coordinate neighborhood basis". In such a way if you name your Jacobian matrix of the map from $(\theta, \phi )$  to $(\xi, \eta)$ as $J$, then you can show all the above computations through the matrix multiplication $(J^{-1})^T g\ J^{-1}$, where $g$ is the matrix form of the mentioned metric on the third line.

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh - I guess that as $\theta=\sin\theta$ for small angles, the $\frac{2\eta\zeta d\zeta d\eta}{\theta^{4}}\left(\theta^{2}-\sin^{2}\theta\right)$ term will vanish near the origin of the $\zeta,\eta$ coordinate system. This then gives the correct metric. Is that right? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075 yes exactly, a very good illustration of this approximation is available in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). There, you can observe that $sin(\theta )$ is equal to $\theta$ in an open interval.

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh - I'm no mathematician and it's been over four years since I looked at this and I've now no idea what Semsen's hint was that allowed me to make the 21 September 2014 edit. Sorry about this, but do you have any idea how I got the first line of that edit? Thanks

Comment: @Peter4075 yes sure, I post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reformulate the argument of the problem in the following equivalent way first (just making it mathematically a bit more accurate):

Denote the north pole by $o$. Then we are given the map (normal coordinates) 
$$\mathrm{exp}_{\ o}^{\ -1}: \mathcal{U}\subset S^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal{U}^\prime \subset T_{o}(S^2)$$
$$\left( \theta, \phi \right) \longmapsto \left( \eta, \xi \right)$$

(where $\mathcal{U}^\prime$  is the neighborhood around $0$ in $T_{o}(S^2)$ on which the exponential map $\mathrm{exp}_{o}$ is a diffeomorphism onto a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $o$ in $S^2$).
If $g = d\ \theta ^ {\ 2} + sin^2 (\theta )\ d\ \phi^{\ 2} $ is the metric tensor on $S^2$ then our goal is to show

$$g^\prime =\mathrm{exp}_{o}^{\ast} (g) = \frac {{\xi}^{2}{\theta}^{2}+{\eta}^{2} \sin ^2 \left( \theta
 \right)}{{\theta}^{4}}\ d \xi ^2 + \frac {{\eta}^{2}{\theta}^{2}+{\xi}^{2} \sin ^2 \left( \theta
 \right)}{{\theta}^{4}}\ d \eta ^2$$

on $T_{o}(S^2)$ where $\theta = \sqrt{\eta^2 + \xi^2}$.

Using the "matrix of the corresponding metric tensor with respect to coordinate neighborhood basis" of $S^2$, we have:

$$g = \left( \begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&  \sin ^2
 \left( \theta \right)  \end {array} \right)$$

Then showing the matrix of $d\ \mathrm{exp}_{o}$ by $J$ we have (note that since $\mathrm{exp}$ is diffeomorphism over $\mathcal{U}^\prime$, we can obtain $J$ by simply computing the inverse of $d\ \mathrm{exp}_{o}^{-1}$) (perhaps you might want to take a look at **Chapter 2, Problem 8, Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity, O'Neil**) :

$$g^\prime = \left( J \right)^{T} g\ J = \left( \begin {array}{cc} {\frac { \cos ^2 \left( \theta \right) 
  \cos ^2 \left( \phi \right) +  
\cos ^2 \left( \phi \right) {\theta}^{2}- \cos ^2
 \left( \theta \right)  -  \cos ^2 \left( \phi \right) 
 +1}{{\theta}^{2}}}&{\frac {\cos \left( \phi \right) \sin
 \left( \phi \right)  \left(  \left( \cos \left( \theta \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+{\theta}^{2}-1 \right) }{{\theta}^{2}}}
\\ {\frac {\cos \left( \phi \right) \sin \left( \phi
 \right)  \left(  \left( \cos \left( \theta \right)  \right) ^{2}+{
\theta}^{2}-1 \right) }{{\theta}^{2}}}&{\frac {-  \cos ^2 \left( 
\theta \right)  \cos ^2 \left( \phi \right)-  \cos ^2 \left( \phi \right)  {\theta}^{2}+
  \cos ^2 \left( \phi \right)  +{\theta}^{2}}{{\theta}^
{2}}}\end {array} \right) 
$$
which upon simplification gives 
$$\left( \begin {array}{cc} {\frac {{\xi}^{2}{\theta}^{2}+{\eta}^{2} \sin ^2 \left( \theta  \right) }{{\theta}^{4}}}
&{\frac {\cos \left( \phi \right) \sin
 \left( \phi \right)  \left(  {\theta}^{2}- \sin ^2 (\theta )\right) }{{\theta}^{2}}}
\\ {\frac {\cos \left( \phi \right) \sin
 \left( \phi \right)  \left(  {\theta}^{2}- \sin ^2 (\theta ) \right) }{{\theta}^{2}}}
&{\frac {{\eta}^{2}{\theta}^{2}+{\xi}^{2} \sin ^2 \left( \theta
 \right)}{{\theta}^{4}}}
\end {array} \right)
$$
Note that this is exactly the matrix of the metric tensor that you have obtained on **21 September 2014 edit** in a more "compact" formulation. Note that at the north pole ($\eta = 0$ and $\xi = 0$), $g^\prime (1,2) = g ^ \prime (2,1) = 0$ and hence we have obtained the metric tensor (note that around $\theta = 0$, $sin (\theta) \approx \theta$ ).

Comment: That is way above my not too bright high-school maths level, but I'm going to spend some time trying to understand it. Forgive my ignorance, but are you multiplying three matrices $g^{\prime}=\left(J\right)^{T}g\ J$ to get the answer? Would you be able to tell me what those three matrices are? The good news is that I've now been able to repeat my 21 September 2014 edit.

Comment: @Peter4075 yes I'm multiplying three matrices, $g$ is mentioned above and $J$ is simply the Jacobian matrix of the map $\mathrm{exp}_{o}$ (in the other word $J$ is $d \mathrm{exp}_{o}$). I used these matrix multiplication to be able to write the equations in a more compact way. Perhaps a look at problem 8 of chapter 2 of Semi-Riemannian Geometry O'Neil would be helpful as I mentioned before. There the induction of the metric tensor is discussed.

Comment: It's taken me a while to realise what's going on. I've posted my realisations in the "answer" below.

Answer (score 3):

Things I didn't realise when I first posted this question.

1. The Riemann Normal Coordinates sit like a little cross centred on the north pole of the two-sphere. One geodesic, the coordinate axis $\xi$, lies along $\phi=0$. The other geodesic, the coordinate axis $\eta$, lies along $\phi=\pi/2$. For small $\theta$ these coordinates are approximately flat (ie Cartesian).
2. So $\xi=\theta\cos\phi$ and $\eta=\theta\sin\phi$ are not, as I suggested, arbitrary definitions.
3. From the definitions of $\xi$ and $\eta$ we can derive $\theta=\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}$.
4. I don't understand Arvin's higher level explanation, so it took me a while to figure out his answer. He is using$$g=J^{T}g^{\prime}J$$ $$g=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}} & \frac{-\eta}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}\\
   \frac{\eta}{\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}} & \frac{\xi}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}
   \end{array}\right].\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0\\
   0 & \sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)
   \end{array}\right].\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}} & \frac{\eta}{\sqrt{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}}\\
   \frac{-\eta}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}} & \frac{\xi}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}
   \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\xi^{2}}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}+\frac{\eta^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)^{2}} & \frac{\eta\xi}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}-\frac{\eta\xi\sin^{2}\theta}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)^{2}}\\
   \frac{\eta\xi}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}-\frac{\eta\xi\sin^{2}\theta}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)^{2}} & \frac{\eta^{2}}{\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}}+\frac{\xi^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}{\left(\xi^{2}+\eta^{2}\right)^{2}}
   \end{array}\right].$$ For small angles, $\theta^{2}\approx\sin^{2}\theta$, $g_{21}=g_{12}=0$ and we have the desired line element $$ds^{2}=\frac{d\xi^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\xi^{2}\theta^{2}+\eta^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+\frac{d\eta^{2}}{\theta^{4}}\left(\eta^{2}\theta^{2}+\xi^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right).$$All this only took me four and half years to figure out.